Can i show a toast while using IO thread? : Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
This is the code, I am trying to open a video in another activity, the problem is only sometimes when the format isn't right I Got the above error, in the most of the time the toast shows without any error. Here is my code:
// Inside fragment
private fun openVideo() {
        val url = viewModel.currentCourseEducation.value?.videoOverviewUrl ?: return
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            url.checkContentTypeForVideo { isVideo ->
                if (isVideo) {
                    Intent(context, VideoViewActivity::class.java).apply {
                        putExtra(AppStrings.VIDEO_URL, url)
                    }.also { startActivity(it) }
                }
                else {
                        getString(R.string.format_not_supported).toast(context)
                }
            }
        }
    }


// On extensions
fun String.toast(context: Context? = App.instance.applicationContext) {
    ToastHelper.currentToast?.cancel()
    ToastHelper.currentToast = Toast.makeText(context, this, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    ToastHelper.currentToast?.show()
}

I tried to do this but I don't know if its a bad example to make nested threads:
private fun openVideo() {
        val url = viewModel.currentCourseEducation.value?.videoOverviewUrl ?: return
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            url.checkContentTypeForVideo { isVideo ->
                if (isVideo) {
                    Intent(context, VideoViewActivity::class.java).apply {
                        putExtra(AppStrings.VIDEO_URL, url)
                    }.also { startActivity(it) }
                }
                else {
                    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        getString(R.string.format_not_supported).toast(context)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


You need to switch to the main thread (UI) to show the toast message if you are running code on the I/O thread.

You mean that the second solution can be used, the one that I've tried above?

You could also use withContext.

Cannot use withContext because i get the error:
Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

First of all I just want to revise some of the thread relation at first. The IO thread is used for the network or database operations. The Main thread is used for the UI related tasks in the Android Application.
In you'r code what I feel could be a problem is that, you are calling the launch function in the scope of the function lambda. Try to clean it a little bit more and see it works:
private fun openVideo() {
    val url = viewModel.currentCourseEducation.value?.videoOverviewUrl ?: return
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val isVideo = url.checkContentTypeForVideo()
        if (isVideo) {
            Intent(context, VideoViewActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(AppStrings.VIDEO_URL, url)
            }.also { startActivity(it) }
        }
        else {
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                getString(R.string.format_not_supported).toast(context)
            }
        }
    }
}

